# Android 9 strange behaviour after app installation

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, xamarin-android-player

I have a strange behaviour with Android 9, on launching the app for first time after installing from Play Store. On launching the app second time, the issue just disappear.

So, there are 2 issues, which can alternate, but they are always there:

1- the cookie manager is not able to read all cookies from a WebView. I have already posted a question on this subject here: [xamarin android 9 cookies read issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52116919/xamarin-android-9-cookies-read-issue)

2- Firebase returns a blank notification token, even if the authorization token is valid and the google-service.json are good. In fact, in android 7 and 8 the firebase notification token is alway right.

To my test I use a Google Pixel 2 XL and I use the Xamarin framework.